# Are all "numbers" just one unit value transformed by a function?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, foundations

I'm a programmer, and I've been thinking about this for some time. I have a saying:

> There are only three specific numbers: 0, 1, and ∞. ∞ is just a special case of 1.

Our base function really just converts a unary value into a string (example: "101") that we can parse in a given base.

Tonight, I've been putting some thought towards this, and I realize - I believe that the entire set of natural numbers can be represented by a recursive function that only works on a unit value, as follows (I apologize in advance for the terrible notation, this is not my forte):

```
// Please ignore the fact that this is invalid code for various, various reasons
N (the set of natural numbers) = add(1) where add(x) = return x + add(x);
```

Following this, I believe that the set of integers can be found as a union of the natural number function and a similar function using `subtract` instead of `add` (resulting in the full set of negative numbers).

Going further, I applied more thought - perhaps the set of real numbers can be applied through division functions for the set of all integers divided by the set of all integers (which we've already established via the functions above).

I suppose my question is this - as strange as it may seem, is there only one unit value? (Or, possibly, a very small subset of seed numbers - perhaps 0 and 1 (and maybe -1 for the complex plane?)) **Is our number system just a system of transforms on top of one unit value?**

If this is a really stupid question, I apologize. It's just that the more I think about this, the more I really wonder about it. There's a good chance that I'm missing something or that this has already been derived, but I'd love to know. I'm sure this community knows much more than I do about this. I hope that this interests all of you as much as it does me.

Comment: If you introduce a division over integer numbers, you only get rational numbers, not every real number. The construction of $\mathbb{R}$ is quite a delicate thing, usually performed through Dedekind cuts or completion of a metric space.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I understand your statement - and from my elementary math classes, I know this. Yet, I can't help but wonder how a set of infinity divided by infinity cannot yield an infinite number of values that satisfy the real set....I learned this, and I know I have some reading to do, but I've also got a lot of thinking to do as well.

Comment: but they are different "kinds" of infinity. Please see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_diagonal_argument

Comment: For example, I understand that the infinite set of even number is half of the set of natural numbers. (I believe the term for this is cardinality but I might be wrong.) I understand the concept but I suppose the formula (or function) for determining real vs rational numbers is not as straightforward as the one for even vs natural...

Comment: To state it plainly, the point is that integer or rational numbers belong to a countable set, real numbers don't.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Just saw your comment. I'm showing my ignorance - please bear with me, sorry!

Comment: I say that often and I keep repeating it because I believe it: we are all here to learn. No need for apologies.

Comment: Last question before I move this to chat - rational numbers are built by a single function that divides an integer by an integer. We know that fractions can be reduced, but prime factors in divisors or dividends cannot. I'm guessing (naively) that this is why we have "gaps" in the set of all rational numbers?

Comment: It may be a naive idea but it is very close to mathematics reality: $\sqrt{2}$ is one of such gaps, for instance.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46231/discussion-between-lunchmeat317-and-jack-daurizio).

Comment: It is quite late now in Italy, so I will join the chat tomorrow. A last comment before I go: think that between two distinct irrational numbers there always is a rational number and vice-versa, but there is no bijective function between rational and irrational numbers. It might look as a horrifying situation, but to deal with such subtleties (and to exploit them at the right time) makes this game really, really fascinating.

Comment: You first comment on natural numbers is an early musing of what leads to something called the Peano Postulates

Comment: @PhillipHamilton Can't edit your post, but in case anyone else stumbles upon my question - the Peano Axioms: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms

Comment: You use the adjective "unary" a lot, but frankly, I cannot decide with which meaning of that term. It can mean "with one argument" for an operation, as in "successor is an unary operation, whereas addition and multiplication are binary operations", or it can mean what is loosely called "base 1" representations of natural numbers, as in "the binary representation of $6$ is $110$, while its unary representation is $||||||$". While the latter certainly relates to your question, you are applying unary to numbers themselves, and this does not make sense. Constants can be seen as nullary operations.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Originally, I was thinking "base 1", but I suppose I was trying to get at the fact that the "numbers" we use on a regular basis are really just collections of one single atomic object, for lack of a better term. I lack the vocabulary for this (math and words don't mix well for me) but I welcome any input you have on the matter.

Comment: As another example of the $0,1,\infty$ trichotomy, I remember in linear algebra talking to the lecturer about the number of points lines can intersect, not at all, once or infinitely many places.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

> the entire set of natural numbers can be represented by a recursive function that only works on a single unary value

Bravo -- this is *exactly* the key insight that is exploited in most standard formalizations of the natural numbers (the most famous of which is called [*Peano arithmetic*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms), if you are curious about the details). The recursive function you refer to, which you denoted `add(1)`, is usually called the **successor function** and written $S$. It's a function from the natural numbers to the natural numbers, which takes a natural number $n$ and returns $n+1$.

To define the natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$, we say that $0$ is a natural number, and for any natural number $n$, $Sn$ is a natural number. This gives us all natural numbers: $0$, $1 = S0$, $2 = SS0$, $3 = SSS0$, and so on.
We also may want to say that $Sn$ is a *new* natural number, one that has not been defined before (so for example, $4 = SSSS0$ is not equal to $2 = SS0$).

Some logics are strong enough that *this definition alone* is enough to define and prove what we want about the natural numbers!
You seem to be interested in formalizing it as a program.
In the proof assistant [*Coq*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coq), we may define the natural numbers as:

```
Inductive naturals : Type :=
  | O : naturals
  | S : naturals -> naturals.
```

This is similar to your code snippet, but unlike yours (which was invalid code) this is perfectly valid code defining the naturals.
Yes, it really is that simple -- nothing else is needed. Even more surprising, we can go from here to define addition, multiplication, exponentiation, prime numbers, and whatever else we like, and *prove* things about these that we want to be true. (Most of the definitions will be recursive, and the proofs will be by induction.) **Once we have the successor function $S$, everything else follows.**

> Following this, I believe that the set of integers can be found as a union of the natural number function and a similar function using subtract instead of add (resulting in the full set of negative numbers).

Yes, this basic idea will work to define the integers $\mathbb{Z}$ from $\mathbb{N}$. The integers could be defined by $0$, the successor function $S$, and a predecessor function $P$ which takes $n$ to $n-1$. Unlike with the natural numbers, we do have to define a special equality (equivalence relation) on the integers, so that $PSn$ and $SPn$ are both equivalent to $n$.

An alternate definition (perhaps more common) is that an integer is an ordered pair $(a,b)$, where $a$ and $b$ are natural numbers, and this represents informally the integer $a-b$. We then have to define what it means for two integers to be equal (an equivalence relation), and we say that $(a,b) = (c,d)$ if $a + d = b + c$.

Once again, either definition may be easily formalized in a programming language like *Coq*.

> Going further, I applied more thought - perhaps the set of real numbers can be applied through division functions for the set of all integers divided by the set of all integers (which we've already established via the functions above).

Introducing division in this way (fractions) will get you from $\mathbb{Z}$ to the rational numbers $\mathbb{Q}$. But it won't get you the real numbers $\mathbb{R}$, yet, which is a MUCH bigger set than $\mathbb{Q}$. There are a *lot* of real numbers -- so many that computationally speaking, we can't really write down most of them. As a theoretical tool, however, it's useful to define this giant set, which we do usually using "Dedekind cuts" or "Cauchy sequences". There are several other less-known ways as well. You can read about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Construction_of_the_real_numbers).

> I suppose my question is this - as strange as it may seem, is there only one unary value? (Or, possibly, a very small subset of seed numbers - perhaps 0 and 1 (and maybe -1 for the complex plane?)) Is our number system just a system of transforms on top of one unary value?

Yes, the idea is that we can start with $0$ as the only base value, and use the successor function $S$, together with a way of constructing ordered pairs (for subtraction and division) to generate all the numbers we need. More generically, we start with one or several base values (*seed numbers*) and one or several recursive constructors (*transforms*) to build up all possible numbers.

We can develop the complex numbers $\mathbb{C}$ from $\mathbb{R}$ using ordered pairs again where $(a,b)$ is $a + bi$.

However, we do have to be careful to understand the limits of our construction. For example, for lots of computations involving natural numbers to be efficient, it is actually essential that they be represented as binary strings and not unary strings of $S$s. So if we care about efficiency, then not all representations are created equal.

Comment: +1 Very thorough response! The topic of efficient number representations is so vast. Here's an older SE question about it that just scratches the surface: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/446664/what-is-the-most-efficient-numerical-base-system

Comment: Related to your great explanation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographical_Number_Theory

Comment: When giving a similar speal, I like illustrating how to implement $S$ in the naive set-based counting of $S(x) := x \cup\{ x \}$, with $0 = \{\}$.  But maybe not wise, as it could confuse things.

Comment: The Computer Science version of this (since @lunchmeat317 says that's his background) is called [Church numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding#Church_numerals). If you understand the basics of JavaScript, I recommend the blog entry [Nothing but Functions - Numbers and Math](http://hexatlas.com/entries/9). It's tied tightly to the foundations of Functional Programming.

Comment: @JoelHarmon Church numerals! I think that's pretty much the concept I've been trying to name. This concept is *extremely* helpful.

Comment: @lunchmeat317 Church numerals are another way of defining the natural numbers (and very important in computer science), but in my opinion not as close to what you were getting at. However, let me know if you have any questions about my answer. I think there are parts of it I may have aimed at too high a level.

Comment: @6005 Nah, the answer's very good as it is and I do understand it. I think that church numerals fit the idea that I was trying to express in terms of deriving a set by applying functions recursively to a single value - it definitely helps in terms of the programming model I had in my mind. I'm not entirely sure what you mean about number efficiency with computations, though - why would unary be less efficient than an arbitrary base in a theoretical sense? There are physical reasons for humans and computers, sure, but isn't that just an artificial problem?

Comment: @lunchmeat317 Consider the number $50$, which in binary is $110100$. In order to even read this number in unary, we have to read through $50$ characters, but in order to read through it in binary we have to read only $6$ characters. It turns out in most algorithms, it is critical we store everything in binary and not unary.

Comment: @6005 Right. Reading through the number - that's a physical issue, but not a theoretical one - it's an artificial limitation. Sure, the way we build algorithms has to be practical, but since a base is just a way to transform a value, it shouldn't matter if we don't do that (in the non-practical sense). In computing we use an encoding that's in Base64, but it's really just to save space, as you mentioned.

Comment: Questions of "efficiency" will always be phrased in terms of resources. Those resources do not have to be physical. For a simple example, you can talk about the limiting behaviour of some efficiency measure as resource size goes to infinity, when in reality of course resources are always bounded. On the other hand, such "unphysical" concepts can still tell us concrete things about physical situations (such as when the resource size is large). The relationship between the physical and the theoretical is what motivates the theory in the first place.

Comment: In this case, the difference between binary (and base-n, for n > 2) and unary representations of numbers is that the former have length proportional to the logarithm of the number. This makes the algorithms for handling them - in any universe, not just ours - fundamentally different.

Comment: @6005 Church numerals and Peano arithmetic are closely related. The usual formulation of Church numerals seemed to me to give the querent an avenue from something he's very familiar with to this new thing he's feeling out.

Comment: @lunchmeat317 if you prefer discussions of complexity - using any base other than unary changes `Ω(n)` into `Ω(log n)`, regardless of physical details.

Comment: @RobinSaunders I've been doing some reading on lambda calculus, which I think applies to the concepts here. Why would the algorithms be any different based on base if it's all just substitution? (Again, from a practical standpoint, I get it. From a theory and fundamental standpoint, I don't see how it's any different. In fact, wouldn't it be less efficient since it's actually just another transform?)

Comment: It occurs to me that maybe I'm not thinking of "efficiency" in the right way. Perhaps "efficiency" in lamdba calculus means "brevity", leading to shorter expressions with more substitutions? If that's the case, I understand the base argument. I must be missing something.

Comment: @lunchmeat317 You can define various notions of "efficiency" for any model of computation, including lambda calculus. So far in this thread, people have mostly discussed time complexity (number of computational steps, as a function of input size), and there is also space complexity (amount of space needed to store intermediate steps in the computation). In either case, the asymptotic behaviour will be independent of the chosen base - up to a multiplicative constant - *as long as that base is > 1*. The reason is that unary is not a "true" base at all, but another way of representing numbers.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "it's all just substitution". Perhaps you are reasoning that converting from one representation of a number to another should take a constant amount of time and thus not affect the "efficiency", but this is not the case. Larger numbers will always require more computational steps to convert than smaller ones. And the faster the representation size grows as a function of the number being represented, the more severe this effect will be. The extra computational steps may occur in series (increasing time complexity) or largely in parallel (space complexity).

Comment: When you mention "shorter expressions" as a possible measure of efficiency, one possible interpretation is that you're referring to the sizes of intermediate expressions in the computation. This is essentially space complexity. Another possibility is to consider the initial expression for the algorithm itself; you would usually consider this to be fixed, but we could also consider different expressions for different algorithms - or different "implementations" of "the same" algorithm. In this case, expression size measures the "complexity" of the algorithm itself. It's independent of the input.

Comment: Before defining the natural numbers, we already have the concept of natural numbers.  For example, the use of Sn above.   What if we start with "A" as the beginning natural number in the Peano system?  Then we generate natural number multiples of "A" and multiplication by a real integer is ok, but not multiplication of two of the successors of i.  I think that underlying all this is a hidden relationship between the starting point and the number of steps in the successor function which must be a natural number.  Maybe the Peano axioms are not independent of others related to set cardinality...

Answer (score 14):

You may be interested in reading about groups, rings, and fields. [Wikipedia is a good place to start](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_structure).

We say that 1 generates all integers under addition and inversion, that is, every positive integer is just a sum of ones, and and every negative integer is just its negation.

If we introduce division, then we get all rational numbers. If we further allow roots of polynomials we get algebraic numbers which include some complex numbers. However, we cannot get all real numbers using algebraic techniques like this--such numbers are called transcendental numbers, e.g. $\pi$ and $e$.

This is a really interesting part of math and not a stupid question at all!

Comment: +1. The phrases "inductive definition" and (less importantly) "term model" are also relevant, especially given the CS background.

Comment: This is AWESOME! :-D Maybe I just like being validated but I'll definitely check this out! I'm no mathematician by any means of the term, but the more I think about this the more interesting I find it. I know that transcendental numbers can't be defined by a single function - they must be defined by a sequence of functions that, for lack of a better term, recurse upon each other, but I was wondering if that's not included within the infinity of real numbers. (From set theory, I know it isn't - I learned this in class - but in terms of infinities I'm not sure how it can't be possible.)

Comment: @lunchmeat317 This really depends on what sorts of functions you are willing to consider. Both π and e can be simply expressed in terms of convergent power series, and there is even a computable function which calculates the nth hexadecimal digit of π directly without needing to calculate any of the others.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to check out [Church numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding#Church_numerals), where each natural number $n$ is *defined* as the function $f \mapsto f^n$; so

- $0 = f \mapsto id$
- $1 = f \mapsto f$
- $2 = f \mapsto f \circ f$
- $3 = f \mapsto f \circ f \circ f$

etc.  It's easy to define a successor function, addition, multiplication, etc. using this style (omitting un-necessary parentheses in function applications by convention):

$$Sn = f \mapsto f \circ nf$$

$$n + m = mS\;n$$

$$n * m = m (k\mapsto n+k)\;0$$

$$n^m = m(k \mapsto n * k)\; 1$$

etc.

While this is mostly used today in a programming / programming languages context, I believe it was originally intended in a foundations of math context (so in math, the natural numbers would be taken to 'mean' the above functions).  Of course, programming and programming languages as we know them today grew directly out of the work in foundations of mathematics during the 1920s and 1930s.